# iphone application crashes only in device and when profiling with instruments

Tags: iphone, crash

I am not able to find the reason of a crash in my iphone app.it crashes only when it is in device.however when the breakpoints are on ,it doesnt crash.After crashing the following log is printed in the organiser console.

```
Mar 21 15:43:16 abc-Ss-iPhone com.apple.SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 1f4

Mar 21 15:43:18 abc-Ss-iPhone ReportCrash[1771] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process aaa[1770]

Mar 21 15:43:18 abc-Ss-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.xxx.aaa[0x3989][1770]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.xxx.aaa[0x3989]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

Mar 21 15:43:18 abc-Ss-iPhone SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'aaa' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have put `NSLog` to find where it is crashing.it is pointing to an area where i am reloading the tableview.

I am doing some calculations in the bg thread and reloading the table in the main thread using the following code:

```
//////////////////////////////in bg thread

if(needToReload){
    NSLog(@"calc end---table refresh called");
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];            
}
```

Comment: Are you profiling a Release or Debug version of the app. If Release then I believe you still should be able to decode the crashlog. Are you getting a crashlog? (When you open Device Logs of that device in XCode Organizer)?

Comment: ok thanks a viewcontroller was getting released early

Comment: can u can mark it as the answer

Comment: No, a comment can't be marked as the answer. You can, however, add your own answer. Unless you want me to add my comment as the answer.

Comment: @Amiramix  what i meant was can u put your comment as the answer so that i can mark it.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question... Did you understand why the app only crashes when profiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you profiling a Release or Debug version of the app? If Release then I believe you should still be able to decode the crashlog. Please check by opening XCode Organizer -> Device Logs for that device.